# How to Replace in PHP Array?

Tags: php, xml

I currently have this code.

```
<?php
$username = 'EMAIL ADDRESS';
$password = 'EMAIL ADDRESS';
$opts = array(
  'http' => array(
      'method'  => 'GET',
      'header'  => sprintf("Authorization: Basic %s\r\nUser-Agent: Foobar!", base64_encode($username.':'.$password))
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
libxml_set_streams_context($context);
$xml =  new SimpleXMLElement(
    "https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom",
    null,
    true);
print_r($xml);
?>
```

And I get the following results when I run the PHP code

> SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [version] => 0.3 ) [title] => Gmail - Inbox for EMAIL ADDRESS [tagline] => New messages in your Gmail Inbox [fullcount] => 1 [link] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [rel] => alternate [href] => http://mail.google.com/mail [type] => text/html ) ) [modified] => 2011-10-27T20:12:38Z [entry] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [title] => SUBJECT [link] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [rel] => alternate [href] => LINK [type] => text/html ) ) [modified] => 2011-10-26T15:45:11Z [issued] => 2011-10-26T15:45:11Z [id] => tag:gmail.google.com,2004:1383746934228011210 [author] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [name] => Webs [email] => EMAIL ) ) )

I want it so that the results do not display "SimpleXMLElement Object", etc, and only display the actual useful info (subject, email content, date, etc)

I have tried using str_replace, but it doesn't work.

Comment: -1 for this question.  The question doesn't display any research effort.  @01jayss - print_r is behaving *exactly as the documentation says it should*.  If it is not doing what you want, perhaps you need a different function.

Comment: Complaining that your vanilla icecream (print_r output) tastes nothing like steak (your XML object) just gets you laughed out of every restaurant in the universe, including Milliways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
echo "Title: ".$xml->title.", tagline: ".$xml->tagline;
```

You may need to add some extra paths to the above depending on the format of the XML.

You could also try

```
print_r((array)$xml);
```

as in:

```
<?php
$xml = "<x><title>Blah</title><fred>bob</fred></x>";
$s =  simplexml_load_string($xml);
print_r((array)$s);
```

which outputs:

```
Array
(
    [title] => Blah
    [fred] => bob
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using print_r() will only give you a human readable output. You can convert it to XML or JSON to be more in compliance on what you want.

Try to convert to json.

```
$json = json_encode($xml);
echo $json;
```